# Navigation Framework issue silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, navigation

If I use the navigation framework in silverlight and say mainFrame.Navigate(URI), does this always call the ctor of the page and create a new object? I create the objects of all my pages in the mainPage as they are used at a lot of places, but since this creates a new object the initializations are lost. Can I not use existing objects with this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to work with the ContentLoader of the Navigation Frame....

Basically do your own implementation of INavigationContentLoader ....

David Poll has a ton of articles on his blog about INavigationContentLoader...

http://www.davidpoll.com/2009/11/30/opening-up-silverlight-4-navigation-introduction-to-inavigationcontentloader/

As well as this nice video + post of karl shifflett on Silverlight TV gives you great understanding...

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/SilverlightTV/Advanced-Silverlight-Navigation-Scenarios-Part-2-Silverlight-TV-39/

http://karlshifflett.wordpress.com/2010/07/07/non-linear-navigation-in-silverlight-4/

let me know if this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot. Going through the material. Will let you know if it solves my issue.

Comment: That was really helpful. I have almost got the whole thing working except for a small hurdle. I have a search page which gets navigated to the first time but if the user searches something again while still on that page then clicking the link does not call BeginLoad on my customLoader and the page does not get updated. Is there a way to forcefully call or refresh the page even when the user is at that page ?

Comment: Ok I used this.MainFrame.Refresh(). That worked. Thanks again for the links.